# How to cope with extension-less source files and tools that rely on extension information?

Tags: c++, header, cscope

C++ code I'm working with is happily using the "no extension needed for header files" rule. This gives me a headache when using tools such as cscope and sloccount on directories containing these files, because these tools ignore extension-less files.

Does anyone know a way to avoid this (except renaming the files or putting symlinks etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the files to use normal convention so that future maintainers don't have headaches trying to figure out what code is where. The no-extension standard include files should be treated as the exception rather than the rule to follow, since the standard doesn't even guarantee they correspond to a physical file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that for all relevant file in the project I'm working on unless I convince everyone else to agree to this.

Comment: It's worth having the discussion.  Fighting your tools is a waste of time, regardless of some theory that it shouldn't matter what extension the files have.